# MySQL 4.1 to 5.1 Replication: "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" and "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" not working

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL 4.1 master with a MySQL 5.1 slave. The binlog format is STATEMENT (the only one supported by 4.1).

The problem is that the triggers ("ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" and "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") are not replicated on the slave.

Suppose I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  PK INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Col1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  Stamp TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (PK)
);
```

**Case 1:** With this statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (PK, Col1) 
VALUES (1, 'Value1') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1 = VALUES(Col1)
```

If a row with `PK` = 1 is already there, then the statement behaves like an `INSERT IGNORE...` (nothing is inserted).

**Case 2:** If I run

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Col1 = 'Value2' 
WHERE PK = 1
```

then `PK` and `Col1` are updated, but Stamp is not.

I hope someone has some insight, as I didn't find anything on the Internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Try making `Stamp` **NOT** NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see the problem. The reason your `Stamp` column isn't updating is because you are setting the value for `Col1` to the same thing it already was. If no values actually change in an `UPDATE` statement, then the `Stamp` field will not update.

For example, if you were updating the value for `Col1` to 'Value2' when it was previously 'Value1', then the `Stamp` field **will** be updated.

If you want to ensure that it always updates, regardless of whether or not any values are actually changed, then you should change your `UPDATE` query to:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Col1 = 'Value1', Stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE PK = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe my example is wrong, because I'm actually updating the row with different data and it's still not working. The Stamp column updates on the master, but not on the slave.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not familiar with a master/slave configuration of MySQL. What is the purpose of that setup? To always have a clone of the database? Would it work for you to modify your query to always explicitly update the `Stamp` column? After re-reading your question I see that it was clearly noted that the problem was that the trigger isn't executed on the slave, but perhaps this could be a solution nonetheless.